# How to put a dynamically created EditText and a Spinner in one LinearLayout?

Tags: android

I am making an automation app. Where user have option to add appliances. In this form by default there is 1 edittext and 1 spinner for 1st appliance then user can more appliances by clicking on button. And new Edittext and spinner will create on click. It is creating perfectly now but i want other appliances options as first 1st appliance show in image - 
[Create Appliance Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxPYy.png)

```
public class CreateAppliance extends AppCompatActivity {

int i = 1;
EditText editText;
Spinner spinner;
List<EditText> ed;
List<Spinner> sp;
String[] arraySpinner;
String room;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_appliance);

    final LinearLayout textLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.textLayout);
    Button btnAddAppliance = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddAppliance);
    Button btnCreateAppliance = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateAppliance);
    final EditText txtAppliance = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.r1);
    Spinner spnAppliance = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnAppliance);
    arraySpinner = new String[]{"ON/OFF", "Dimmer"};
    ed = new ArrayList<EditText>();
    sp = new ArrayList<Spinner>();

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arraySpinner);
    spnAppliance.setAdapter(adapter);

    btnAddAppliance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            i += 1;
            editText = new EditText(CreateAppliance.this);
            spinner = new Spinner(CreateAppliance.this);
            editText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            spinner.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            editText.setHint("Appliance" + i);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            textLayout.addView(editText);
            textLayout.addView(spinner);
            ed.add(editText);
            sp.add(spinner);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**activity_create_appliance.xml**

```
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".CreateAppliance">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/r1"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Appliance 1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnAppliance"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </Spinner>

        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/textLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAddAppliance"
            android:text="Add Appliance"
            android:background="@drawable/button_rounded"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/light_blue_900"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/plus"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCreateAppliance"
            android:text="Create Appliance"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/button_rounded"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/light_blue_900"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want dynamically created edtitext and spinner same as this

Comment: I have 1 linear layout i.e textLayout where i am showing dynamically created edittext and spinner. Added full xml file in question. @Abhishek

Comment: This is ids u mentioned @Abhishek

Comment: It is in code. Check full xml file.

Comment: I uploaded my answer. Check it if helps. You have to set your background resources, I removed because they are not present with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this it will work as per your requirements**

> First of all I made some change in your activity_create_appliance.xml. Please view it carefully. Set backgrounds as your requirement. I removed it. Now Updated XML file is as below.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/parentConstraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddAppliance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:text="Add Appliance"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCreateAppliance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:text="Create Appliance"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Now main logic when click is performed is here

```
    final LinearLayout textLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.textLayout);

    Button btnAddAppliance = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddAppliance);

    final ArrayList<LinearLayout> linearLayoutArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    btnAddAppliance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(CreateAppliance.this);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutParams);
            linearLayout.setId(View.generateViewId());

            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            linearLayout.setWeightSum(3);

            EditText editText = new EditText(CreateAppliance.this);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams editTextLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);

            editText.setLayoutParams(editTextLayoutParams);
            editText.setMaxLines(1);
            editText.setId(View.generateViewId());

            linearLayout.addView(editText);

            Spinner spinner = new Spinner(CreateAppliance.this);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams spinnerLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2f);

            spinner.setLayoutParams(spinnerLayoutParams);
            spinner.setId(View.generateViewId());

            String[] arraySpinner = new String[] {
                    "ON", "OFF"
            };

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CreateAppliance.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner);

            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

            linearLayout.addView(spinner);

            linearLayoutArrayList.add(linearLayout);

            textLayout.addView(linearLayout);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all create a edittext or spinner layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</EditText>
```

then you inflate this to where are you want dynamically

```
    btnAddAppliance.onclick{

        RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent);
        View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        parent.addView(child);
}
```

you can also see [link](http://rajeshvijayakumar.blogspot.com.tr/2013/03/inflating-ui-dynammically-example-in.html)